# Correct way of passing a self variable as argument to a mixin parent method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, mixins

I have to model a warrior and the different kinds of attacks he can perform. The idea is to use mixins to contain the attack logic. I have my classes defined in the following way:

```
class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, energy):
        self.energy = energy


class TemplarKnight(Warrior, HandToHandCombatMixin):
    pass


class CombatMixin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attacks_cost = {}

    def attack(self, attacker, attack_cost):
        if attacker.energy < attack_cost:
            print('Not enough energy to attack')
        else:
            attacker.energy -= attack_cost
            print('Attack!')


class HandToHandCombatMixin(CombatMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.attacks_cost['sword_spin'] = 10

    def sword_spin(self, attacker):
        return self.attack(attacker, self.attacks_cost['sword_spin'])
```

But the problem comes when I try to test this setup. When I do

```
class TestTemplarKnight(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.templar = TemplarKnight(energy=100)

    def test_templar_knight_can_sword_spin(self):
        self.templar.sword_spin(self.warrior)
        self.assertEquals(self.templar.energy, 90)
```

I get

```
    def sword_spin(self, attacker):
        return self.attack(
>           attacker, self.attacks_cost['sword_spin'])
E       AttributeError: 'TemplarKnight' object has no attribute 'attacks_cost'
```

It seems that Python thinks that the parameter `self.attacks_cost` (when calling `self.attack()` inside the `sword_spin()` method of the `HandToHandCombatMixin` class) belongs to the `TemplarKnight` class instead of the `HandToHandCombatMixin`.

How should I have written this code to make Python look for `self.attacks_cost` inside `HandToHandCombatMixin`?

Comment: *All* the `__init__` methods in this case should be using `super()`.

Comment: Attributes don't really belong to classes; they all belong to the same instance, but each one only gets created if the `__init__` method that sets them gets called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `super` correctly, *all* the classes involved need to use it.  Right now, `Warrior.__init__` is called first, but it doesn't use `super`, so `HandToHandCombatMixin.__init__` is never called.

Make the following additions:

```
class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, energy, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.energy = energy


class TemplarKnight(Warrior, HandToHandCombatMixin):
    pass


class CombatMixin:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.attacks_cost = {}

    def attack(self, attacker, attack_cost):
        if attacker.energy < attack_cost:
            print('Not enough energy to attack')
        else:
            attacker.energy -= attack_cost
            print('Attack!')


class HandToHandCombatMixin(CombatMixin):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.attacks_cost['sword_spin'] = 10

    def sword_spin(self, attacker):
        return self.attack(attacker, self.attacks_cost['sword_spin'])
```

Now when you instantiate `TemplarKnight`, you'll guarantee that all the `__init__` methods are called, and in the correct order. Eventually, once of the calls to `super()` will cause `object.__init__` to be called, at which point the chain finally ends. If you are correctly handling the keyword arguments, `**kwargs` will be empty by the time that happens.

Comment: The only change that was needed was the addition of `super().__init__()` at the beginning of the `Warrior` class. It made no difference in the output of the test to add the same call at the beginning of `CombatMixin`. Why would that be?

Comment: At least in *this* case, `CombatMixin` is the last class (before `object`) in the MRO of `TemplarKnight`, and `object.__init__` doesn't really do anything, so it doesn't matter if it doesn't get called. But, there could be some *other* class that `CombatMixin` doesn't know about that *could* have an MRO with `CombatMixin` in a different position, so you still need to use `super` to avoid breaking the chain.